# Sequence using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a function which outputs all possible combinations of char list with length and without any repeats like aa, bb etc.

I am now on this stage:

```
def sequences(char_list, n, lst = []):
    if len(lst) == n:
        print(lst)
    else:
        for i in range(len(char_list)):
            temp_list = [char_list[j] for j in range(len(char_list)) if i != j]
            sequences(temp_list, n, lst + [char_list[i]])

print(sequences(["a", "b", "c"], 2))
```

Output is correct but I have None at the end. I actually have no idea why.

```
['a', 'b']  
['a', 'c']  
['b', 'a']  
['b', 'c']  
['c', 'a']  
['c', 'b']  
None
```

And what is the best way to get strings in the output and not lists?

Comment: You *don't* print `None` at the end, it is just that the REPL informs you that you have no return value.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `itertools`? This function already exists

Comment: @JohnColeman it's not the REPL, it's the `print` statement at the end of the file.

Comment: @SethPeace Good point. I didn't see that line. Of course, the function itself doesn't do the printing.

Comment: Replace `print(lst)` with `return lst` and `sequences(temp_list, n, lst + [char_list[i]])` with `return sequences(temp_list, n, lst + [char_list[i]])`.

Answer (score 1):

The function `sequences` doesn't return anything (there's no `return` statement anywhere in the code), so it'll automatically return `None`. `print(sequences(["a", "b", "c"], 2))` will execute this function and print its return value, outputting `None`.

To get strings instead of lists, concatenate all the strings in the list like this:

```
print(''.join(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every function has an implicit `return None` at the end of it. On the last line of your code, you asked Python the print the output of `sequences`, which is `None` since no return value was specified.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was is that I printed it at the end once again.